# UIWebView "steals" images from another .webarchive file

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios8, webarchive

there is a uiwebview controller which loads a .webarchive page depending on row touched in parent UITableViewController.

code is very simple:

```
var state: String! //this string comes from prepareForSegue() in parent table view 
var requestURL: NSURL?

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

switch state {

//great number of cases
//...

case "cascsPics":
requestURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("cascsPics", withExtension: "webarchive")


case "techPics":
requestURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("techPics", withExtension: "webarchive")

//...
}
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL))

}
```

.webarchive files are prepared and copied to the project folder.
The strange thing is - there are two cases (listed above), when web view "steals" images from one webarchive to another=))) 
When i load first webarchive - it loads right. But the second uses images corresponding to the first! Order of loading doesn't matter. Everything loads well except of images!

I tried to use this:

```
if let reqURL = requestURL {

let req = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!, cachePolicy:     NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 0.0)

webView.loadRequest(req)

}
```

Also i tried to clear all cache in viewWillDisappear (and viewDidDisappear as well).
Tried to load an empty page into a webview in viewWillDisapper - nothing helpes!
Just a mysterious behavior!)

Thank you very much if you can help me=) My app is in the appstore and i can not fix this stupid bug!=(

Comment: any solution on this? We have the same problem